# Cross reference an equation in different files

Tags: cross-referencing

I am not sure that there is an answer to this question, but I try.

I am writing two papers; in the second I often reference to some equations reported in the first: how can I use `\eqref` and `\label` so I do not have to track all the changes in the numeration of the equations?

The papers are separated documents, I am not using `\input` to merge them in one file (like one does with thesis' chapters for example).

**EDIT** In [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53292/51537), the OP sais:

> I have a **main document (manuscript)** and a **supplemental
>   document**.

But, as I said, my papers are *separated* files, there are no main document and supplement document.

Comment: See the `xr` package, which I think will help.  Not sure if this is related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123609/help-with-cross-referencing-and-altered-numbering-schemes

Comment: In the linked question, the OP also says 'I wonder if there is a way that I can "link" the two (make them recognize each other) so that section, equation, and figure references across documents are recognized?' That sounds exactly the same to me.